# TikZ loop avoiding values in a given list

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have a loop which avoids elements in a specified list, ideally something like this:

```
\def\list{{1,3,6}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
  if "\i not in \list" do {...} else do {... }
 }
```

which should do something for \i=2,4,5,7 but not for \i=1,3,6.

I am very  new to TikZ, but still hope that it's clear what I'm asking ...

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? And don't `\def\list` !

Comment: why should I not \def\list ? what are the disadvantages, and what would be better?

Comment: `grep '\\list' $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/tex/latex/base/*`. (Or whatever the equivalent command would be on Windows or for MikTeX.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\newif\ifoneofthese
\oneofthesefalse
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}%
  {%
    \oneofthesefalse
    \foreach \j in {1,3,6}%
    {%
      \ifx\i\j \global\oneofthesetrue\fi
    }%
    \ifoneofthese\relax\else \i{} is not in the list. \fi
  }
```

[image: conditional loops]

## EDIT

This works fine with a macro for the exclusion list:

```
\newcommand*\mylist{1,3,6}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}%
  {%
    \oneofthesefalse
    \foreach \j in \mylist
    {%
      \ifx\i\j \global\oneofthesetrue\fi
    }%
    \ifoneofthese\relax\else \i{} is not in the list. \fi
  }
```

produces identical output to the original version:

[image: macro version]

## Complete Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifoneofthese
\oneofthesefalse
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}%
  {%
    \oneofthesefalse
    \foreach \j in {1,3,6}%
    {%
      \ifx\i\j \global\oneofthesetrue\fi
    }%
    \ifoneofthese\relax\else \i{} is not in the list. \fi
  }
\newcommand*\mylist{1,3,6}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}%
  {%
    \oneofthesefalse
    \foreach \j in \mylist
    {%
      \ifx\i\j \global\oneofthesetrue\fi
    }%
    \ifoneofthese\relax\else \i{} is not in the list. \fi
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. But how can I replace {1,3,6} by a list variable? Writing \def\list{1,3,6} and then \foreach \i in \list seems not to work. You mentioned earlier that \def\list{1,3,6} should be avoided ... But since I would like to have the code run on arbitrary platforms, your grep replacement is not a good solution. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @GandalfLechner `\def` redefines any command that happens to have the same name. In other words, it doesn't check if the command exists or not. So you might inadvertently overwrite an existing Tex command. `\newcommand` is the overlapping command that does the check and works in a similar way.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\def` *after* `\begin{document}` shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: @GandalfLechner The `grep` is not an alternative to `\def\list`. It is an explanation for why you ought not do `\def\list`. `\newcommand` would indeed be preferable because compilation would fail with an error. And, yes, that really would be better here.

Comment: @Alenanno ???? Why on Earth would `\def` be any better after `\begin{document}`? If you are overwriting a kernel command or TeX primitive or command from another package, you are still overwriting it. `\newcommand` would indeed be better here because compilation will fail: it will *tell* you `\list` is a bad choice.

Comment: @cfr I remember I read it somewhere here on Tex.SE. :P

Comment: @Alenanno You should never believe anything you read on the internet ;).

Comment: @cfr So not even you right now? :P

Comment: @Alenanno Exactly! *Especially* not me right now.

Comment: @GandalfLechner It works fine for me with a macro for the exclusion list. Please see edit above.